# Product Catalog Item missing in the web database

Tags: sitecore-commerce, publishing

After successfully installation of Sitecore Experience Commerce 9 Update 2, I published all the content from master to web. Everything is working perfectly but one thing I noticed that Product Catalog item (under `/sitecore/content/Sitecore/Storefront/Home/`) is missing from the  web database.

1. Is it a expected behavior of commerce?
2. If not, what could be the reason?
3. If yes, Why is it so?

[image]

Comment: have you followed the post installation steps?

Comment: I am publishing with admin user so don't need additional user creation and i have updated the storefront theme. Is this issue related to these steps in anyways?

Comment: it is not related to admin user, more likely to happen, with indexing

Comment: I have encountered same behaviour even though there are no publishing restrictions or workflow which is holding publishing. This item is just skipped.

Comment: I have had the same issue, I transfered the item through the control panel _(Move an item to another database)_ and everything was fine.

But no idea why the item can't be published...